# Using Google Volley with Square Tape on Android

Tags: android, android-volley, square-tape

Android noob here. I have been asked to fix an app some other noobs wrote for a hand held device a couple of months ago. The problem with it is that the devices are mostly used in areas where network is unreliable and weak. As a result, most of our data upload requests fail.

The original authors decided to roll their own REST client and also did not implement any persistence. I am thinking of replacing those with proven networking and caching libraries. Specifically, I am think of using `Google Volley` for networking and `Square Tape` for persisting upload data. I am a little low on confidence as my searches are not throwing up any instances of this combination being used.

Does `Volley` make `Tape` redundant? Does `Volley`'s caching and retry mechanisms give the same functionality as `Tape`'s queue? I can see a plus for `Tape` to prevent data loss due to app crashes but otherwise would I still need `Tape` if I use Volley?